# How to create CallCredentials from SslCredentials and token string

Tags: c#, python, authentication, grpc

I am porting a gRPC client from python to c#.  Both the python client and the c# client are using the gRPC Framework from grpc.io.

The python client uses the following code to open a secure, non-authenticated channel, which it then uses to procure a token string, which it then uses to create call credentials with the grpc.composite_channel_credentials() function:

```
channel = grpc.secure_channel(url_server_address, ssl_creds)
stub = gateway.GatewayStub(channel)

# Acquire access token via password authentication
pw_cmd = gateway.PasswordAuthenticateCmd(account_name=url.username, password=url.password)
auth_rsp = stub.PasswordAuthenticate(pw_cmd)

# Open a secure, authenticated channel
auth_creds = grpc.access_token_call_credentials(auth_rsp.access_token)
composite_creds = grpc.composite_channel_credentials(ssl_creds, auth_creds)
channel = grpc.secure_channel(url_server_address, composite_creds)
stub = gateway.GatewayStub(channel)
```

In c#, I have been able to compile the protocol buffer definitions, and connect with the generated client to successfully acquire the access token:

```
SslCredentials secureChannel = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText(SSLCertificatePath));
Channel channel = new Channel(ServerURL, PortNum, secureChannel);

var client = new GrpcClient(new Grpc.Gateway.GatewayClient(channel));
var response = client.client.PasswordAuthenticate(new PasswordAuthenticateCmd() { AccountName = UserName, Password = UserPassword });

Console.WriteLine(response.AccessToken);
```

From here, however, I can't find the c# analog to the grpc.composite_channel_credentials() function to take the SslCredentials and the access token string to create combined credentials.

None of the examples here https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html here use a token string, and I haven't been able to find any other examples out there.

Comment: Any specific reason as to why are you not using the standard gRPC C# client https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

Comment: I will update the question: I am using exactly that.  Everything in both the pyton and the c# code in my question uses the grpc library from grpc.io.

Comment: What you're looking for is: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c5311260fd923079637f5d43bd410ba6de740443/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/CallCredentials.cs#L49

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem using CallCredentials.FromInterceptor().

The grpc.access_token_call_credentials() python call adds an authorization entry to the metadata, and sets its value to "Bearer " + AccessToken, so I just had to do the same:

```
SslCredentials secureCredentials = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText(SSLCertificatePath));
Channel secureChannel = new Channel(ServerURL, PortNum, secureCredentials);

var client = new GrpcClient(new Grpc.Gateway.GatewayClient(secureChannel));
var response = client.client.PasswordAuthenticate(new PasswordAuthenticateCmd() { AccountName = UserName, Password = UserPassword });

var accessTokenCredentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor(new AsyncAuthInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
{
    metadata.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + passwordResponse.AccessToken);
    return TaskUtils.CompletedTask;
}));

var authenticatedCredentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(secureCredentials, accessTokenCredentials);
Channel authenticatedChannel = new Channel(hostURL, hostPort, authenticatedCredentials);
```

As [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5454771/jan-tattermusch) pointed out in his answer, there is a function in the Grpc.Auth namespace that does the same thing as the function that I wrote: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c5311260fd923079637f5d43bd410ba6de740443/src/csharp/Grpc.Auth/GoogleAuthInterceptors.cs#L58

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm following your example but I get an error "Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Empty update")'". Did you ever see this one?

Comment: @BenCameron I don't recall having that problem.  When I was having my problem, I already had a working server and client app, and was just porting the client.  Are you able to connect to the server with a different app?

Comment: yes I have another client connecting to the server but its a .net core 3.1 app. I uses a different auth lib. The client I am working on now is a  standard 2.0 app. It works when the connection is unsecured but doesn't work with ssl and jwt auth.

Comment: What .net version is your client? @James

Comment: Also was your cert a .pem file?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c5311260fd923079637f5d43bd410ba6de740443/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/CallCredentials.cs#L49 and https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c5311260fd923079637f5d43bd410ba6de740443/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/ChannelCredentials.cs#L67.

Feel free to also look at:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c5311260fd923079637f5d43bd410ba6de740443/src/csharp/Grpc.Auth/GoogleAuthInterceptors.cs#L58

Comment: Thanks Jan! I actually solved the problem before, but had forgotten to post it as an answer.  As you can see, I manually created the BearerTokenHeader.  I'll mark my answer as the solution since it's the one that I used, but I'll refer to this link as well.